# How can I remove icons from the application panel in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome

[image: [Example](http://i.imgur.com/gwZGr.png).]

I really dislike the look of having that icon up there.

Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score -1):

Try holding `Alt` then right clicking on the icon

Comment: You're thinking of GNOME Panel (as seen in the GNOME Classic session). That answer will not work here :)